# SSIS Stage data from values in a local table

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am staging data from two separate data servers onto a staging server - one server contains the order information and the second server contains shipping information for that order.  I am pulling across all orders modified within the last 5 days.  I then want to load all the associated shipping information for those modified orders.  So there are 3 servers in this scenario - the Order server, the Shipping server and the Staging server.

I tried to do a for-each container based on the list of staged orders - but with a result set in the 1000's it is a VERY slow solution.

I can't make changes to the Order or Shipping server - but I can do whatever I need on the Staging server.

What I really want to do is create a Variable object with a list of order numbers and then in my Shipping server select statement have a a filter like this:

select [shipping fields] from [shipping_table] where order_nbr in [variable_list_of_order_nbrs]

Comment: What part of the task is slower? I mean whether it is order server or shipping server or staging server?

Comment: looping through each of the ~2000 orders to fetch the shipping information one-by-one is slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your shipping information is well-indexed, one thing that can be very quick is a Lookup transformation with 'No Cache' selected.

If you need to pull back more than one row, that can be trickier, but it is doable with an asynchronous Script transformation to create placeholder row numbers, and then a modified Lookup SQL statement (with a ROW_NUMBER() field) to ensure you pull back all required rows and each row only once.

Comment: how do I use a lookup to retrieve information?  I have only used it the filter information.  I don't want to stage ALL the shipping data and then filter it - I would prefer to only stage the desired shipping data.

Comment: As a basic 1-1 row match, you would use the Lookup transformation to look up on some key, e.g., OrderID, or whatever you have. You would then pull this information from the shipping table. You'd only be running the orders you were interested in through this component, so you'd only be pulling back the shipping information for those.

Comment: sorry - I am being dense.  How to select 2000 rows from the Shipping table based on what I have staged for orders.  The way I understand the Lookup transformation my source query would need to scan the entire table and the Lookup transform would filter out what is needed.  Correct?  I'll try it though...

Comment: That's correct, but if you have 'No Cache' on, your Lookup query will be looking for one record at a time (rather than caching the whole table), and if your shipping table is well-indexed (i.e. on the lookup key(s)) then it will be very quick.

Comment: I assumed it be too inefficient - but it is quick.  Thank you.

Comment: But it was WAY faster with Full Cache selected?  Which isn't the setting you suggested - can you explain why?

Comment: It would depend on the size of the shipping table. So if it's not that large, SSIS will be able to cache it quite quickly. But if we're talking millions of rows, 'No Cache' will likely be quicker (but again, this would depend on indexing).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how efficient this solution is, but just came out of my mind with my SQL skills:
Note: This requires change in Order serve and Shipping server fetching logic

Fetch the all record data from source (Order serve) as XML data

```
DECLARE  @Product Table (
ID INT)

INSERT into @Product
select top 10 ROW_NUMBER() over(order by a.name)  as Rcount
from sys.all_objects a --used here for demo to generate series of numbers

--Return as XML
SELECT T.ID  
FROM @Product T
FOR XML path('')
```

Then pass this xml data as input parameter to Shipping server. Fetch the records joining the output from XML parameter.

```
DECLARE @XMlVal XML 

set @XMLVal = (SELECT T.ID  
FROM @Product T
FOR XML path('')
)

--Read from XML
SELECT 
prod.value('(.)[1]', 'int') AS 'ID'
FROM
@XMLVal.nodes('/ID') AS temp(prod)
```